# how to remove invalid characters from xml in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a xml which consists of lot of text like below:

```
<EmployeeId>&EmpId;</EmployeeId>
<Department>&Dept;</Department>
```

I need to remove the & character, so that it will be proper xml to validate it against the xsd. How can achieve this?

Comment: But you'll be completely changing the XML. Why not encode them instead?

Comment: UTF encoding is not solving the issue

Comment: Not UTF-8 encode. XML entity encode. Meaning replace `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: The `&EmpId;` looks like an external entity reference. If you're receiving XML containing this reference, then I would expect the DTD to contain a definition of an entity called EmpId, and I would expect you to parse the XML using entity expansion to replace the entity reference by the contents of the defined entity. Unless you do that, I wouldn't expect the XML to be valid against any schema.

Comment: please let me know how to expand entities using C#, I have not worked with DTD before so I have no idea :(

Comment: my entities were expanded successfully using this reference in xml (<!ENTITY writer SYSTEM "http://www.w3schools.com/entities.dtd">), but now I am facing problem with doctype, I want to attach a external dtd to my xml using C#, I dont want to use the dtd already attached in the doctype as its not valid.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

`xml = "<myxmlnode>"+ SecurityElement.Escape(string) +"</myxmlnode>"` when creating your nodes.

This will take care of all the invalid characters ans escape them.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was doing individual replace on each invalid characters.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend removing data just to "fix" an issue. The correct way to add the `&` character to Xml data is `&amp;`. You could use the `XmlWriter` or some other class from the framework to create Xml and let it figure out the formatting for you.

Comment: This is a third party xml, my only concern is that this xml is not getting validated against the xsd, its stopping whenever this character is encountered. Is there any other way to validate the xml completely ignoring these illegal characters?

Comment: You could 'fix' the Xml by using the `myXmlString.Replace("&", "&amp;");` in the other answer, but it remains risky as you'd break an Xml that _is_ valid using that replace operation. In the end, supporting something that's broken remains a pain in the rear.

Comment: It is stopping because the XML isn't valid, so the XSD/XML parser has done its job.

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of the following:

```
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("PATH");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("PATH", content.Replace("&", String.Empty));
```

or

```
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("PATH");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("PATH", content.Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("&", "&amp;"));
```

The "double Replace" is to avoid creating "&amp;amp;".

Comment: This will not solve the issue as all valid unicode characters will get replaced.

Comment: Maybee you could read the XML into a XDocument and loop over all elements and check for invalid &...

Answer (score 0):

Some characters need to be encoded properly if they are used in XML.  The ampersand & is one of them.

Have a look here, you will need to encode these characters if they are a part of your data contained in the XML.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316063

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at the [XMLConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx) class. You can use it to encode and Decode XML to make it safe.  This will also handle illegal characters as defined in the [XML Spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)  As pointed out already, removing text such as &amp would actually change the underline data, therefore you should really encode and decoded as needed.